# Can reboot system restarting the service as systemctl does?

Tags: linux, 3g

I've modified the file in

```
/etc/config/network
```

After modifying this, I need to execute the following command make it take effect.

```
systemctl restart netifd
```

However, for some reasons, the systemctl is no longer available in my system. Hence, I wonder may reboot system can take the same effect as "systemctl restart netifd" does ?

Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: Yes. I think it is better to say `systemctl restart` does the same thing to a service that reboot does.

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha thanks, please answer the question in the reply.

Comment: What distribution are you using?

Comment: WindRiver 5.0 - this is the linux distribution i currently use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command:

```
service netifd restart
```

Concerning your question: yes, rebooting your computer will have the effect of restarting all the services that are set to run at boot, but it's quite a brutal way to go if you just need to restart one service. Much better to find a solution for the latter.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running systemd (most Linux distributions released in the last couple of years do), then the absence of `systemctl` suggests that you've seriously broken your system. In that case nobody can say for sure (given the information in the question) whether your system will even come back up after a reboot.

If you're not running systemd (because you either replaced it or are running a distribution which doesn't use systemd), you're following a guide that is not suitable for your setup. Without more knowledge of your setup we can't say whether your change will have any effect in that case.

Please edit the following information into your question:

- What Linux distribution (including version) do you use?
- What have you done to systemd – or what might have happened that has caused the absence of `systemctl`?
- What are you trying to achieve?